# ¿Puede "hopefully" traducirse como "ojalá"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

Buscando la traducción de **"hopefully"** [en WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=hopefully) veo que se menciona

- con suerte
- con optimismo

Sin embargo, me pregunto: ¿podría también traducirse como **"ojalá"**? Según la RAE, esta es su definición:

> [**ojalá**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=zsgSoYxJsDXX2NPhNZFk)
>
> (Del ár. hisp. law šá lláh, si Dios quiere).
>
> 1. interj. Denota vivo deseo de que suceda algo.

Comment: Habría que indagar en la diferencia entre _esperanza_ ("hope") y _deseo_ (como figura en la definición de "ojalá").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutamente. Como absolutivo, *hopefully* en inglés significa, efectivamente, *I hope that...* (espero que), aunque quizás un pelín más impersonal (como *se espera que*).

*Ojalá* efectivamente significa lo mismo, y yo de hecho lo uso en, que sepa, todas las situaciones en que usaría *hopefully*.

Answer (score 4):

*Ojalá* me suena a un poco más expresión de deseo, aunque no necesariamente me implica la existencia de *algún sustento* que me haga creer que algo pueda efectivamente ocurrir.

*Hopefully* sí me da la idea de que hay motivos para creer que pueda ocurrir el evento, aunque está un poco supeditado a la suerte o aleatoriedad.

En general no me animo a traducir *hopefully* como algo más que *con un poquito de suerte*, aunque, también es cierto: no tengo muchos más fundamentos que mi opinión como hispanoparlante nativo :) (de Argentina, si eso hiciera diferencias)

Answer (score 1):

### Ojalá que sí [u otro algo].

Literalmente significa `hopefully`.  Español lleva una cultura religiosa mientras el ingles no se la lleva.

Ojalá es una palabra árabe también, que se refiere a [Alá](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al%C3%A1).

Mientras tanto, `ojalá` sigue siendo traducido por `hopefully`.